# Will Node 12.12.0 become a Stable LTS Release Today?

Tags: node.js

Today, Node 12 is supposed to go into stable long term support status:

[image]
source: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

At the time of this typing, Node 12.12.0 is still considered "current":

[image]
Source: https://nodejs.org/

My question is, does the Node version typically increment to another sub-version on the day it becomes stable?

For example, will 12.12.0 become stable today, or will it likely be 12.12.1 instead?

I realize this may seem like a silly question, but I'd like to go ahead and upgrade now if 12.12.0 will be the LTS release, while if 12.12.1 will be it, I'd want to postpone this upgrade until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered same day as OP, looks like here's your answer:

[image]

You'll likely see the next current bump to 13.0.0?

Comment: Yeah, I was just coming here to post the same screenshot. Interesting. Yeah, I suspect 13.0.0 will become the current soon.